# suppose for $a$ and $b$ we have $(a,b)=1$ ,show that the biggest common divisor of $a^2+b^2$ and $2ab$ is 1 or 2.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

suppose for $a$ and $b$ we have $(a,b)=1$ ,show that the biggest common divisor of $a^2+b^2$ and $2ab$ is 1 or 2.

I did some elementary calculation on the property of bcd but no good success  will achieved,please give me your idea about it,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Any common divisor of these would also be a divisor of $a^2\pm2ab+b^2=(a\pm b)^2$.

Comment: It might also be of interest to remember that if a prime number $p$ is a factor of $xy$ then it is a factor of $x$ or a factor of $y$. If we put $y=x$ we obtain the implication $p|x^2 \implies p|x$